# JMeter custom SoapSampler Message part Manifest was not recognized

Tags: xml, soap, jmeter

I use [Custom Soap Sampler](https://github.com/spinning10/JMeterSoapSampler/wiki) to attach files to `SOAP` requests in `JMeter`. I use XML version 1.0 and SOAP version 1.1. I selected attachment and set content ID to `ref1` and set type to resource.
`SOAP` envelope contains reference to file here:

```
<data><xop:Include href="cid:ref1" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></data>
```

I get error message as response:

> Message part {http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader}Manifest
>   was not recognized. (Does it exist in service WSDL?)

I checked raw request and found, it is different than standard ones. It starts with following lines:

> ------=_Part_6_231845394.1524218533567 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I unchecked `Update ebXML attachment references in SOAP body` option and after that it is working correctly.